# fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory compilation terminated in opencv4

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

In opencv4 while compiling code, I am getting this error:

```
fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I properly installed opencv4.
Why am I getting an error?

Comment: My guess would be that you installed opencv4, and the source code is obviously expecting to be compiled by opencv2. That's pretty much what the error message says, doesn't it?

Comment: /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/videoio.hpp:46:28: fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory
IOTSource/subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'IOTSource/main.o' failed
compilation terminated.
make: *** [IOTSource/main.o] Error 1

Comment: above one is the error got in.

Answer (score 4):

Try installing the `-dev` or `-devel` package for OpenCV2 to get the header file.

`sudo apt-get install libopencv-core-dev` on Debian and Ubuntu, and `sudo yum install opencv-devel` on Fedora.

Once that's done, append `$(pkg-config --cflags opencv)` to your compiler command:

```
export CC="gcc $(pkg-config --cflags opencv)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but posting it here for future references.

If you're using OpenCv for Node.js with the npm package `opencv4nodejs` which in turn has a dependency on `node-gyp`, this error is expected when the package installation path contains whtespaces. `node-gyp` is known to not handle whitespaces well.

So, ideally the path shouldn't be something like this `C:\Program Files\some_dir`.

Try installing the package in a path without any whitespace and it should work.